# How can I specify mulltiple namespaces in one Fargate profile via Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am deploying EKS to AWS via Fargate. But how can I set multiple namespaces in one `aws_eks_fargate_profile` section?

I have tried below two config but none of work.

```
selector {
    namespace = ["example", "default"]
  }
```

```
selector {
    namespace = "example, default"
  }
```

Below is the full configuration:

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "example" {
  cluster_name           = aws_eks_cluster.example.name
  fargate_profile_name   = "example"
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  subnet_ids             = aws_subnet.example[*].id

  selector {
    namespace = "example"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can have more than one selector?

Answer (score 0):

Define selector block twice to specify multiple namespaces.

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "example" {
  cluster_name           = aws_eks_cluster.example.name
  fargate_profile_name   = "example"
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  subnet_ids             = aws_subnet.example[*].id

  selector {
    namespace = "example"
  }

  selector {
    namespace = "default"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can added multiple namespace like this,

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "example" {
  cluster_name           = aws_eks_cluster.example.name
  fargate_profile_name   = "example"
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  subnet_ids             = aws_subnet.example[*].id
  selector =[{namespace = "example"},{namespace = "example2"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify up to 5 selectors per Fargate Profile and use wildcard support as well:

```
  selector =[{namespace = "default"}, {namespace = "example?"}, {namespace = "*-staging"}]
```

This would match `default`, `exampleA`, `exampleB`, `appA-staging`, `appB-staging`, and any other namespaces that fit these selectors.